# Access list field from QueryDocumentSnapshot

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know how to access a field that is a list of Strings from QueryDocumentSnapshot object in flutter.

It works if I access the item in the list directly like `element['tags'][0]`
Is there a way to get the 'tags' field to a list of Strings ? Or to get the size of the list to recreate it by separately getting each item?

```
Future<UserData> getUserData() async {
   QuerySnapshot userExpenses = await getUserExpenses();
   List<Expense> expenses = [];
   userExpenses.docs.forEach((element) {
      Expense e = new Expense();
      e.description = element.get('description');
      e.price = element.get('price');
      e.tags = [];
      e.tags.add(element.get('tags')[0]);
      e.id = element.id;
      expenses.add(e);
   });
   ........
}

Future<QuerySnapshot> getUserExpenses() async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('expenses')
        .where('uuid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
        .get();
}

class Expense {
  late String id;
  late String price;
  late String description;
  late List<String> tags;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a bit more, like your code, and a screenshot of how the document looks in firebase and the string you want to access.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad How do I populate the list of tags in the expense object without knowing how many there are in firestore ?

Comment: @adi.neag Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69977887/13171940) helped with your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the test I made, it is not necessary to use the `add()` method to assign `element.get('tags')` to the `e.tags` field.

Since you are initializing an array for your `e Expense` object, you can assign it straight away using the `=` equal operator.

But, just remember that when you assign a variable, both elements in the assignment has to be of the same type because if you do as the following:

```dart
e.tags = doc.get('tags');
```

You will get this error:

> errors.dart:187 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type 'List'

Because [`List<dynamic>` is not a subtype of `List<String>`](https://newbedev.com/dart-how-to-convert-list-dynamic-to-list-string-in-flutter-code-example)

From there, we should [cast the `List<dynamic>` into `List<String>`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18979#issuecomment-401623710) to match the type, like this:

```dart
e.tags = List<String>.from(doc.get('tags'));
```